# Is using "as-clause" at the end of the sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Just checking a sentence for my friend and in the last paragraph, I found this sentence long and difficult to follow, yet he claimed that this is grammatically correct, what do you guys think?

> From my point of view, despite the possible demerits of using robots, the merits brought by robots are so significant and irreplaceable that people should continue using robots **as they are playing a vital role in boosting future development.**

My problem is with this as-clause. I think this should be written into a separate sentence, like: 
They are playing a vital role in boosting future development.

Comment: It is grammatically correct. As to whether it is better to split it into two sentences, that's primarily opinion-based. If you are not asking only whether it is grammatical but are asking what might be wrong with it or how it might be improved, that's a request for proofreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the *as clause* as such, but I would agree that the sentence would benefit from a bit of reorganisation - possibly by breaking it into two. And you definitely don't need the word *robots* three times.

How about the following?

***My view is that despite their possible demerits, the significance and irreplaceability of robots mandates their continued use. They are playing such a vital role in boosting future development.***